# Python: Guessing game gone wrong

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a small, basic guessing game in python, something like Text Twist. Here's the code:

```
while game_running == True:
    if (tries_left != 0):
        print "Tries left: " + str(tries_left)
        chosen_text = text_list[picker(text_length)]
        scrambled_text = scrambler(chosen_text)
        print "Guess the word/s: " + scrambled_text
        guess_text = raw_input("Your answer (space included): ")
        if (chosen_text == guess_text):
            print "Congratulations! You guessed correctly!"
            game_running = False
        else:
            tries_left-=1
    else:
        print "LOL. You dun goofed son. Terminating like SkyNet..."
        game_running = False
```

Out of sight functions:

- picker - basically a randomizer
- scrambler - scrambles the words. In progress and not yet implemented.

You have 3 tries to guess correctly, or the app terminates. If you guessed correctly, the app displays a message, then terminates. Sounds simple enough.

**The Problem:**

I could not get this to work:

```
if (chosen_text == guess_text):
```

Even though I'm 100% sure (via `print chosen_text`) that I guessed it right.

**What I Tried:**

I tried reversing the order, putting `str()` around them, and even reversing the flow of the if and else, using `is` instead of `==`, and removing the tries function, fwiw.

Nothing could get it to go true...
...unless I hard-code `chosen_text`, and guess that correctly.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try checking the length of each string, are they the same? It may contain newlines or whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to insert some debugging code:

```
print repr(chosen_text)
print repr(guess_text)
```

This will show you exactly what two strings you are dealing with. The `repr` function will put quotes around the strings, and let you identify whether there are unexpected spaces or other difficult-to-see issues with your strings.

If there are, you might try something like:

```
if chosen_text.strip() == guess_text.strip():
    print "Congratulations! You guessed correctly!"
```

Or if there are differing capitalizations:

```
if chosen_text.strip().lower() == guess_text.strip().lower():
    print "Congratulations! You guessed correctly!"
```

There are some other things you could do to make your code more Pythonic / more in the Python idiom. For example:

```
while game_running == True:
```

is better stated as:

```
while game_running:
```

But those few other cleanups are stylistic, and not related to your comparison difficulty.

Comment: The `.strip()` worked, thanks. And thanks as well for the tip of repr(). Never would've guessed.

Comment: It's useful in a lot of situations to not test `A == B` directly, but rather `func(A) == func(B)`, where `func` is a function that does some kind of cleanup, "folding," or hashing operation. In this case, running both sides of the comparison through `.strip()` and/or `.lower()` methods is the equivalent of the `func`.

Comment: `repr()` btw means "representation." It's giving you the "programmer's view" of the data, whereas `str()` gives more the "intended for normal user input/output" view of the data.